# C#/ASP.NET MVC: how to register/log in a different web application if I know username & password?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, integration

I have a primary web app with authentication on example.com, and I have a secondary app with authentication on subdomain.example.com

I want the 2nd app to be integrated with the first one. So once a user registers and logs in, s/he doesn't have to register/log in again.

It is possible to send a post request, but this won't generate the cookies in user's browser...

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're able to set a cookie so that it works on all subdomains (www, subdomain, etc.).  See [Basics of Cookies in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vbtchaspnetcookies101anchor7):

> By default, cookies are associated with a specific domain. For example, if your site is www.contoso.com, the cookies you write are sent to the server when users request any page from that site. (Except for cookies with a specific path value, as I explained in the section immediately preceding.)
>
> You can also use the Domain property to create a cookie that can be shared among multiple subdomains. For example, set the domain as follows:

```
Response.Cookies("domain").Value = DateTime.Now.ToString
Response.Cookies("domain").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
Response.Cookies("domain").Domain = "contoso.com"
```

> The cookie will then be available to the primary domain as well as to sales.contoso.com and support.contoso.com.